# how to write the name and ip of the virtual machine in inventory.ini.tmpl using terraform, if it is created?

Tags: terraform

The virtual machine is created using terraform version 13.5.

The virtual machine have variable name_b (which are interesting to me)

Main code for create virtual machime

```
resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "b" {
  count         = var.create_b == "true" ? 1 : 0
  name          = "b"
}
```

If I do not want to create a virtual machine:

```
create_b = "false"
```

it is necessary that the name of the virtual machine are recorded in inventory.ini, if it is created.

```
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {
 content = templatefile("inventory.ini.tmpl",
 {
  name_b                = vcd_vapp_vm.b.name,
 }
 )
 filename = "inventory.ini"
}
```

How to avoid the mistake?

```
Error: Missing resource instance key

  on outputs.tf line 12, in resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory":
  13:   name_b      = vcd_vapp_vm.b.name,

Because vcd_vapp_vm.b has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed
on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    vcd_vapp_vm.b[count.index]
```

I try add [count.index] to resource

```
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {
 content = templatefile("inventory.ini.tmpl",
 {
  name_b                = vcd_vapp_vm.b[count.index].name,
  
 }
 )
 filename = "inventory.ini"
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

  on outputs.tf line 12, in resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory":
  13:   name_b                = vcd_vapp_vm.b[count.index].name,

The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data"
blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

I try add check special variable

```
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {
 content = templatefile("inventory.ini.tmpl",
 {
  name_b                = var.create_b ? vcd_vapp_vm.b.name : null,
  
 }
 )
 filename = "inventory.ini"
}
```

Error

```
  on outputs.tf line 12, in resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory":

  13:   name_b                = var.create_b ? vcd_vapp_vm.b.name : null,

Because vcd_vapp_vm.b has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed
on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    vcd_vapp_vm.b[count.index]
```

Try

```
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {
 content = templatefile("inventory.ini.tmpl",
 {
  name_b = try(vcd_vapp_vm.b.name, null)
 }
 )
 filename = "inventory.ini"
}
```

Error

```
Error: Missing resource instance key

  on outputs.tf line 12, in resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory":
  13:   name_b = try(vcd_vapp_vm.b.name, null)

Because vcd_vapp_vm.b has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed
on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    vcd_vapp_vm.b[count.index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn’t output to a file natively.

See https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html

What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to write those variables values to a file?

Comment: Thanks for answer! A try and add may examples to questuion.